# Need your assistance with Windows cmd shell script

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion, cmd, directory

I have following script that removes all subdirectory from ROOT directory and removes all  files in a ROOT directory except *.bat files.

```
pause
FOR /R C:\Temp\ %%F IN (*.*) DO IF NOT "%%~xF" == ".bat" DEL /F /S "%%F"
for /d %%i in ("c:\Temp\*") do rmdir /s /q "%%i"
pause
```

Help me improve script that it can also scan files *.bat in a ROOT subdirectories and remove all files with other extensions.

Comment: So, what needs to be deleted? Only files or also child folders ?

Comment: this script shoud delete all files in a ROOT subdirectories except all *.bat files in those sobdirectories

Comment: If one of ROOT subdirectories does not contain any *.bat files then it removes too

Comment: & why was it tagged under `bash`? (I untagged it now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test. If what it shows in console is what needs to be done, remove the `echo` command from destructive lines keeping the `rmdir` or `del` commands.

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    set "root=c:\temp"

    rem For the %root% tree
    for /r "%root%" %%d in (.) do (

        rem Test for the presence of .bat files under directory 
        dir /s /b "%%~fd\*.bat" 2>nul | find /v "" > nul 
        if errorlevel 1 (

            rem If there is no .bat files under directory, remove directory
            echo(**** rmdir /s /q "%%~fd"

        ) else (

            rem There are bat files in directory or under it. Remove anything else in this directory
            for %%f in ("%%~fd\*") do if not "%%~xf"==".bat" echo(-------- del "%%~ff"

        )

    )
```

EDITED - To adapt to comments - How to adapt the code so it will process more than one root folder? Take the code and convert it into a subroutine, then call it with the corresponding root. Iterate over the list of root directories

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    for %%r in ("c:\temp" "c:\temp2" "c:\temp3") do call :processRoot %%r

    endlocal
    exit /b

:processRoot
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "root=%~1"

    rem For the %root% tree
    for /r "%root%" %%d in (.) do (

        rem Test for the presence of .bat files under directory 
        dir /a /s /b "%%~fd\*.bat" 2>nul | find /v "" > nul 
        if errorlevel 1 (

            rem If there is no .bat files under directory, remove directory
            echo(**** rmdir /s /q "%%~fd"

        ) else (

            rem There are bat files in directory or under it. Remove anything else in this directory
            for %%f in ("%%~fd\*") do if not "%%~xf"==".bat" echo(-------- del "%%~ff"

        )

    )
    endlocal
    goto :eof
```

Comment: Too bad that i can't Vote Up

Comment: Script can't recognize a hidden *.bat file and permanently remove the directory with hidden *.bat files. How to add recognizing a hidden *.bat files?

Comment: How to make a multiply root path in this script?

Comment: @MichaelT: Updated. Maybe not the cleaner way of doing it, but it requires no aditional testing. If it works for one root, it "should" work for more roots. As the only thing that changes is the initial variable, adapt to take its value from a parameter to the subroutine and keep the rest of the code.